# Inject Jenkins secret into Nuget.config file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:
Create a Jenkins Secret Text. Inject it into the Nuget.config in the source as a password into the packageSourceCredentials section. But the value shows up as all *** in the configuration file. Is this even possible?

Comment: Jenkins sanitizes output in the Console Log. Is it possible you're seeing the result of that sanitized output and the NuGet.config itself is fine?

Comment: My bad...I was consoling out the config file which is the reason for the masking ... the actual file did get the correct value in the workspace ... closing the issue...